# Carbon - Float Difference in Months Filtered

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I'd like to perform this operation (filtering out weekends), but have the result returned in float months:

```
$weekdiff = ($carbonFrom->diffInDaysFiltered(function(Carbon $date) {
return !$date->isWeekend();
                }, $carbonTo) + 1) / 5;
```

Is there a way to get the float difference in months between two dates while filtering out weekends?

Thank you!

Comment: Months have a different number of days. A result that contains fractions of a month makes no sense.

Comment: Carbon can return a fraction of a month no problem, and it's smart enough to take into account the different number of days. However, I cannot get it to filter out weekends.

Comment: For the record there is `diffInWeekDays` equivalent to `diffInDaysFiltered` with `!$date->isWeekend()`

Comment: For your question, are you suggesting to count full months as 1 + partial months as (number of week days) / (number of week days in the whole month) ?

Comment: What result do you expect for $from = '2022-02-25' and $to = '2022-04-14' ? The number of days without a weekend is simple. But the number of months with fractions?

Comment: For a period of 2022-02-25 - 2022-04-14, Carbon floatDiffInMonths returns 1.6591397849462

Comment: Carbon floatDiffInMonths returns incorrect results. Example: For the period '2022-01-31' - '2022-03-01' returns 0.9354.. A value >1 would make sense.